# Jquery functions and Ajax Calls not working when httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" used?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I was using below code in web.config. But these settings are not working. My Ajax calls and Jquery function are not working. This website on load balance. What needs to be change? any alternatives?. I tried from code also.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" protection="All" timeout="240" loginUrl="Login.aspx" 
           slidingExpiration="true" requireSSL="true" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>

<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN reference for HttpOnly cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcookiessection.httponlycookies(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The httpCookies element supports the use of HttpOnly cookies. HttpOnly
>   cookies (cookies with the HttpOnly attribute) were introduced in
>   Internet Explorer 6 to help mitigate the risk of cross-site scripting.
>   *The HttpOnly attribute prevents cookies from being accessed through
>   client-side script.* Any information contained in an HttpOnly cookie is
>   less likely to be disclosed to a hacker or a malicious Web site. For
>   more information, search MSDN (msdn.microsoft.com) for "HttpOnly."

Emphasis mine. My assumption is that you are trying to access one of your HttpOnly cookies client-side which is not permitted. Alternatively, note that because you've specified requireSSL="true", your cookies won't even be there if your request is non-SSL.

Past that, show some codez as we're otherwise just making educated guesses.